# Trigger on IsMouseOver requires large StrokeThickness

Tags: wpf

I have the following control set as the Child of a WinForms element host (WPF Interop).  It seems when the the StrokeThickness is set to low values (i.e. 1), the IsMouseOver property is not consistently set and the correct styling does not appear.  I confirmed the issue is not with WinForms, since I also tested the functionality in a WPF app.  This is causing me issues because I'm using these rectangles as hidden overlays on a custom charting control.  When the mouse enters a certain region of the chart, it becomes highlighted.  Are there additional property constraints (i.e. StrokeThickness) when using the IsMouseOver property?

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've not set a background (`Fill`) for the rectangle. As such, the mouse is only considered over the rectangle when it's over the stroke. Set the `Fill` to something other than `null`, even if it's `Transparent`.

Comment: Yes, but then I loose the ability to set the Fill property in the Trigger.  As an alternative, I created a secondary trigger to set the Fill to transparent when IsMouseOver == false.  This seems to work.  Let me know if you have any concerns with this approach.

Comment: You don't need opposite Triggers. If you use a Setter in the Style (<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>) then the Trigger will override that value while it's active and reset when it becomes inactive again. This is not the case if you set the Fill as a local value on a Rectangle, as local values take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I was unaware that triggers can override style setters.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to `true`. The issue may be that your stroke is only rendering as a "half" pixel, so the mouse event doesn't work as expected.

*Edit:* Alternatively, you might want to explicitly set the rectangle background to `transparent` when it's not moused over.